# Sum timestamps based on a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like this:

| Timings | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 20.12.2022 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 20.12.2022 00:00:15 | 0 |
| 20.12.2022 00:00:45 | 1 |
| 20.12.2022 00:05:00 | 1 |
| 20.12.2022 00:05:15 | 1 |
| 20.12.2022 00:05:45 | 0 |
| 20.12.2022 00:06:00 | 0 |
| 20.12.2022 00:06:15 | 1 |
| 21.12.2022 00:06:40 | 1 |
| 21.12.2022 00:07:00 | 0 |
| 21.12.2022 01:07:00 | 0 |

I need to calculate the amount of time when the value is equal to 1.

In the above table, it will result in (**20.12.2022 00:00:45** to **20.12.2022 00:05:15**) + (**20.12.2022 00:06:15** to **21.12.2022 00:06:40**) = 4min 30sec + 24hr 0min 25sec = 24hr 4 min 55 sec (24:04:55).The measure should not overflow if the calculated value is above 24 hours.

I tried to calculate the value using the following DAX measure:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(Tabelle1[Timings]),FILTER(Tabelle1,Tabelle1[Value] = 1)) - CALCULATE(SUM(Tabelle1[Timings]),FILTER(Tabelle1,Tabelle1[Value] = 0))
```

Sum of the timings when the value is 1 - Sum of the timings when the value is 0.This measure is giving me an incorrect answer.

How to write a DAX expression to calculate this?

Comment: and you have a hell of rows, right?

Comment: According to your definition, a single timestamp with value = 1 does not count if both the preceding and the following timestamp have value = 0. Strange.

Comment: There will not be a single row with value=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this calculated column to your table:

```
Delta1 = 
VAR _this_timings = 
    Tabelle1[Timings]
VAR _this_value = 
    Tabelle1[Value]
VAR _prev_timings =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Tabelle1[Timings]),
        FILTER(
            Tabelle1,
            Tabelle1[Timings] < _this_timings
        )
    )
VAR _prev_value = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Tabelle1[Value]),
        FILTER(
            Tabelle1,
            Tabelle1[Timings] = _prev_timings
        )
    )
VAR _delta =
    DATEDIFF(_prev_timings, _this_timings, SECOND)
RETURN
    IF(_prev_value = 1 && _this_value = 1, _delta, 0)
```

and then use this measure to get your result:

```
Sum Delta1 = 
VAR _seconds = SUM(Tabelle1[Delta1])
VAR _minutes = INT(_seconds/60)
VAR _remaining_seconds = MOD(_seconds, 60)
VAR _hours = INT(_minutes/60)
VAR _remaining_minutes = MOD(_minutes, 60)
RETURN
    _hours & ":" 
    & FORMAT(_remaining_minutes, "0#") 
    & ":" & FORMAT(_remaining_seconds, "0#")
```

[image]

Comment: The calculated seconds value is correct in the column. I am not seeing anything wrong in the measure that you have written. But I am seeing incorrect value when I plot the measure.

Comment: You didn't mention "plotting" in your question. What exactly are you trying to do? What is the visual, what are the fields? I've got zero problem plotting the Delta1 column over the Timings.

Comment: By plotting I mean visualising using the _Card_ as you have done below the code. Yes, I too dont see any problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Difference in Seconds =

VAR Durations=
    ADDCOLUMNS(
           tbl
           ,"@Duration"
                ,VAR currentT=[Timings]
                VAR currentV=[Value]
                VAR prevT=
                    CALCULATE(
                        MAX([Timings])
                        ,'tbl'[Timings]<currentT
                        ,All()
                    )
                VAR prevV = 
                        CALCULATE(
                            SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[Value])
                            ,'tbl'[Timings]=prevT
                            ,All()
                        )

                RETURN 
                    SWITCH(
                        TRUE()
                        ,currentV=prevV,DATEDIFF(prevT,currentT,SECOND)
                        ,0
                    )
    )

VAR Sum1 =
        SUMX(
            FILTER(
                Durations
                ,[Value]=1
            )
            ,[@Duration]
        )
VAR Sum0 =
        SUMX(
            FILTER(
                Durations
                ,[Value]=0
            )
            ,[@Duration]
        )
RETURN
    Sum1-Sum0
```

Comment: The number of seconds were wrong with this measure.